# Calculating net area in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, area

I'm working with California wildfire data (1990-2020) in ArcGIS Pro. There are about 8,400 fires in the dataset. The acreage of each fire is included. I think it is highly likely that some land has been burned more than once in the past 30 years.

Question: How can I calculate the **net** acreage of land burned in wildfires one or more times as opposed to **total** acreage burned during the 30-year period?

Second question: Is there a way to identify land burned multiple times during the 30-year period?

Comment: While you've been here in GIS SE a while, you haven't yet taken the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Questions with bulleted lists of questions in them are vulnerable to being closed as lacking *focus*. In addition, the ArcGIS 10.0 tag references a *really* ancient build of Desktop, long before Pro was released, so your only tag is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 3):

To find the net area, assuming the burned area data is in vector format, you could use the [Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) tool on the overlapping polygons.

[image]

[image]

Regarding counting the number of times an area has burned. This is code that will count overlapping polygons. It is written in PyQGIS because it has been a long time since I have used ArcPy, but perhaps someone will be kind enough to translate it.

```py
## function to make a QgsVectorLayer of a single QgsFeature
def feature_to_new_layer(feature, targetCRS):
    ## create QgsVectorLayer with desired geometry
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=' + targetCRS, 'extracted_area', 'memory')    
    ## open an edit session on the new layer
    lyr.startEditing()
    ## add fields to new layer based on feature's current fields
    [lyr.addAttribute(x) for x in feature.fields()]
    ## commit changes to fields
    lyr.updateFields()
    ## add feature to new layer
    lyr.addFeature(feature)
    ## finish editing
    lyr.commitChanges()
    return lyr
    
## get reference to the burned areas map layer (a polygon layer called 'burned areas')
burned = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('burned areas')[0]

## union burned areas to create a polygon of every overlap
burned_union = processing.run("native:union", {'INPUT':burned,'OVERLAY':None,'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

## get reference to the layer's data provider
burned_union_prov = burned_union.dataProvider()

## add a new field to store the count of intersecting features
burned_union_prov.addAttributes([QgsField('intersecting', QVariant.Int, "integer", 10)])
burned_union.updateFields() 
burned_union.commitChanges()

## get features of unioned layer
feats = burned_union.getFeatures()

## iterate through features
for f in feats:
    ## get feature id
    fid = f.id()
    ## make new layer of each feature
    area = feature_to_new_layer(f, 'EPSG:4326')    
    ## get intersection of each feature with all the burned areas
    feature_intersection = processing.run("native:intersection", {'INPUT':burned,'OVERLAY':area,'INPUT_FIELDS':[],'OVERLAY_FIELDS':[],'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']    
    ## get number of intersecting features per feature
    num_intersecting_feats = len(list(feature_intersection.getFeatures()))    
    ## update the attribute table with the number of intersecting features
    burned_union_prov.changeAttributeValues({fid:{0: num_intersecting_feats}})

## rename layer and add to map canvas
burned_union.setName('burned area count')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(burned_union)
```

[image]